# Intuition behind the notion of proper morphisms in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intuition, schemes

I'm in understanding the intuition behind the notion of proper morphisms and also how people think about it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_morphism

A morphism of schemes $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is proper if it is separated, finite type, and universally closed.

I also know it generalizes the notion of a proper map in topological spaces.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map

But what is not clear to me why separated and universally closed are the right ways to generalize this.

Also, how do people generally think about proper morphisms?

Comment: Honestly, I think of them as projective morphisms, which is untrue of course, but you asked for intuition as well as facts. And the projective morphisms _are_ an undeniably significant class of proper morphisms.

Comment: It literally says on the Wiki page that one can define proper maps, for Hausdorff spaces (hint hint separated) using universally closed. That doesn't satisfy you? :)